# Array of enums - convert to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, enums, nsarray

Having

```
enum {MyA, MyB, Null};
typedef NSNumber myEnum;
```

Or

```
typedef enum {MyA, MyB, Null} myEnum;
```

1) How do I create an array

```
myEnum* myEnumTemp[] = {MyA, MyB};
```

Just gives `"Implicit conversion of 'int' to NSNumber* is disallowed with ARC(ref. counting)`

2) If you are able to create an array how to convert it to `NSArray`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to do it this way :

```
typedef enum { MyA, MyB, Null } myEnum;
```

Then, to create an array, wrap the numbers into `NSNumber`s objects :

```
NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:MyA],
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInteger:MyB],
                                       nil];
```

Comment: for lazy people you can do it this way (requires Xcode 4 or higher): NSArray *a = @[@(MyA),@(MyB)];

Answer (score 9):

In Obj C:

```
enumArray = @[@(enum1),@(enum2)];
```

In Swift:

```
enumArray = NSArray(objects: enum1.rawValue, enum2.rawValue);
```

Answer (score 7):

Basically, you need to wrap the value in a [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object.

```
#define INT_OBJ(x) [NSNumber numberWithInt:x]

[array addObject:INT_OBJ(MyA)];
```

And there was nothing wrong with your other array, you just should have defined it like this:

```
typedef enum {MyA, MyB, Null} myEnum;

myEnum values[] = { MyA, MyB };
```

The problem was that you defined myEnum as a `NSNumber`, which is not equal to an enum value (int).

Comment: For the second way can we do that using a mutable array?